# How to configure PHPMD (PHP Mess Detection) in Zend Studio

Tags: php, zend-studio

I've installed the PHP PTI Tools as plugin in Zend Studio. I can find options to configure the PHP Version and used PEAR libraries for PHP Depend, PHP Copy Paste Detector and Code Sniffer. But not for PHP Mess Detector.

Is there some way to configure it? It always uses the built in PHP 5.4 version from Zend Studio 9 and nothing else. The output from using it from the context menu gives:

> /Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/com.zend.php.debug.debugger.php54.macosx_5.4.0.v20120214/resources/php54/php-cgi -c /var/folders/9t/z7lbvftx6m3gs9jfqqfw5v1r0000gp/T/zend_debug/session6059915200436834623.tmp -d asp_tags=off -d short_open_tag=on /Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.tools.phpmd_0.1.0.R20110628000000/php/tools/phpmd.php /Users/sebey/Sites/sb/customer/app/include/library/Customer/Cms/Definition xml /Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/ZendStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/file:/Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000.jar!/php/library/PEAR/data/PHP_PMD/resources/rulesets/codesize.xml,/Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/ZendStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/file:/Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000.jar!/php/library/PEAR/data/PHP_PMD/resources/rulesets/naming.xml,/Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/ZendStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/file:/Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/org.phpsrc.eclipse.pti.library.pear_1.2.2.R20120127000000.jar!/php/library/PEAR/data/PHP_PMD/resources/rulesets/unusedcode.xml
>   dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/zend/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/com.zend.php.debug.debugger.php54.macosx_5.4.0.v20120214/resources/php54/php-cgi
>     Reason: image not found

Either my project is ok and has no flaws.... which I somehow kind of doubt.... ;-)

Comment: Library not loaded: /usr/local/zend/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient.16.dylib Referenced from: /Applications/Zend Studio.app/Contents/Resources/Java/plugins/com.zend.php.debug.debugger.php54.macosx_5.4.0.v20120214/resources/php54/php-cgi Reason: image not found

Comment: @VoronoiPotato yeah, I've seen that. But I would rather tell PHP MD to use my own PHP 5.3 version that I have configured with PEAR and all, then to fix the build in 5.4 version